# Kendo DropDownListFor sends unexpected request

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to use server side filtering depending on characters entered in the dropdownlist.
I am using following code:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.VoucherReceiverCustomerId)
                  .Name("VoucherReceiverCustomerId")
                  .DataValueField("Value")
                  .DataTextField("Text")
                  .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
                  .AutoBind(false)
                  .MinLength(1)
                  .Delay(250)
                  .DataSource(ds => ds
                          .Read(read => read.Url(Url.Action("Customer_List", "Customer")))
                          .ServerFiltering(true)
                      )
                  .Events(evt => evt.Filtering("test").Open("test2"))
            )
```

I'd expect the list to send the dataSource request after the user entered at least one character.
But in fact the list immediately sends the request after clicking on the dropdownlist (in order to enter characters). Moreover neither event `Filtering` nor `Opening` fire.
Increasing parameter for option `MinLength` to > 1 results in the actual expected behaviour.

To work around this issue I could use the `Filtering` event and manually request the dataSource after a character has been entered.
But how would I prevent the dataSource from reading until then?
Normally setting option `AutoBind` is enough but in this case not.

Answer (score 0):

Funny - setting option `MinLength` to **0** actually behaves as one would expect for value **1**.

So I kind of got a solution now. However, the documented problem still exists.